# Django 1.9.3 - How to pass HTML template to index template

Tags: python, ajax, django, templates

So, I have the index template and in there I have a table that uses Django template language to create a table (using for).

How do I pass the same table (even with Django templating code) to the index template using AJAX? I already added the AJAX portion and it works, but the DJango code is not interpreted and the table is not constructed.

Basically, I would like to:

- Separate individual DOM components in "templates" so via AJAX I push to the main (index) template as needed. Please keep in mind that these "templates" should contain Django code like `{% for item in data %}`.

For instance:

From the view:

```
def getDetails(request):
 var = "{% if 10 > 5 %}<h1>TRUE</h1>{% endif %}"
 return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(var),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

index.html:

```
function getDetails() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "getDetails/",
        type : "POST",
        data : { getDetails : $('#postValue').val() },

        success : function(json) {
            $('#postValue').val('');
            $("#tableDetails").html(json)

    <div id="tableDetails"></div>
```

What the browser displays:

```
{% if 10 > 5 %}
TRUE
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You'll need to give a bit more detail. Why can't you render the template fragment in the view that responds to the Ajax call? Why don't you want to pass any context there?

Comment: I can pass the context containing the HTML table. The problem is that to create the table I am using the template language (since it is pretty simple) when the index template receives the table, it renders everything, including {% for items in collection %} for instance. So the server is not interpreting the Python code.

Comment: But that didn't answer my question: why can't you render the template in the Ajax view, like you would with any other view? Maybe you should show the full code of that view.

Comment: I actually did. I can do it, but it does include the {{ }} tags.

Comment: I edited the post for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that this code:

```
def getDetails(request):
  var = "{% if 10 > 5 %}<h1>TRUE</h1>{% endif %}"
  return HttpResponse(
    json.dumps(var),
    content_type="application/json"
  )
```

literally just puts that template code into a string and sends it as a JSON object. At no point does the template code get converted to a HTML string.

From your comments, you imply that the server doesn't interpret template code, but this isn't correct! Django's default views most certainly do get involved.

You can do this interpretation yourself using the Template class.

Try the following code:

```
from django.template import Context, Template
template = Template("{% if 10 > 5 %}<h1>{{ value }}</h1>{% endif %}")

def getDetails(request):
  context = Context({"value": "TRUE"})
  output = template.render(context)
  return HttpResponse(
    json.dumps(output),
    content_type="application/json"
  )
```

The above example, adapted from [the Django 1.9 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context), demonstrates programmatically using a Template, as well as supplying additional information using a Context object.

---

Perhaps a better alternative is to leave your template code in a partial template file somewhere. For example, let's say you've created `table.html` containing the following template code:

```
<table>
{% for item in items %}
  <tr><td>{{ item }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Then you can load and render it as follows:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def getDetails(request):
  table_rows = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']
  output = render_to_string("table.html", {"items": table_rows})
  return HttpResponse(
    json.dumps(output),
    content_type="application/json"
  )
```

This invocation of `render_to_string` will load template code from `table.html`, and dynamically create a context using the supplied dict. In this case, the `items` entry in the Context is set to an array so that the `{% for %}` tag can loop through it.